# Autofilter a Range excluding two dates

Tags: vba, excel, date, autofilter

I have the below code, In L1 I want to select all dates except for yesterday and today and in M1 unselect all. I able to do the same in M1 but unable to perform the action in L1.

```
Range("L1").Select
ActiveSheet.Range("$A$1:$U$3804").AutoFilter Field:=12, Operator:= _
    xlFilterValues, Criteria2:=Array(1, "2/11/2016", 1, "3/31/2016", 2, "4/5/2016", 2, _
    "4/6/2016", 2, "4/7/2016", 2, "4/8/2016", 2, "4/11/2016", 2, "4/12/2016", 2, "4/13/2016", _
    2, "4/14/2016", 2, "4/15/2016", 2, "4/18/2016", 2, "4/19/2016", 2, "4/20/2016", 2, _
    "4/21/2016", 2, "4/22/2016", 2, "4/25/2016", 0, "10/28/2015")
Range("M1").Select
ActiveSheet.Range("$A$1:$U$3804").AutoFilter Field:=13, Criteria1:="="
```

*From user's Comments:*

I have data from Column A to U. I have many criterias to select in every column. In Column L there are only dates. What I want to achieve is Unselect dates of yesterday and today and select all other dates present. thats it. My task will be completed there

Comment: You cannot do thjat with AutoFilter. Use a dictionary to built an array for the filter criteria.

Comment: Thanks @Jeeped I tried doing that but I'm unable to get it to yesterday and today's date... Please help me with the code.

Comment: No problem but your data pattern is unclear. Does column L have both integers and dates in it? Do you want all of these as well as all blanks in column M? Is there any column in A:U that is unique? Can you do it manually at all or is it impossible to do manually?

Comment: In Column L there is only date values and the rest I have completed. I want to get the dates unfiltered from the range in L column. I can do it manually but not through the code. there are no uniques vaues in A:U.

Comment: OK, so you can filter on the dates in column L successfully. If you want to 'unfilter' column L then use `ActiveSheet.Range("$A$1:$U$3804").AutoFilter Field:=12` (no other parameters).

Comment: There are ways to improve your code (notably [Range.CurrentRegion property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff196678.aspx)) but I am hesitant to write a full answer as I am still unclear on what you are trying to do and how your data is set up.

Comment: Let me start from first. I have data from Column A to U. I have many criterias to select in every column. In Column L there are only dates. What I want to achieve is Unselect dates of yesterday and today and select all other dates present. thats it. My task will be completed there.

Answer (score 0):

> <sup>In Column L there are only dates. What I want to achieve is Unselect dates of yesterday and today and select all other dates present. thats it.</sup>

Filter for all dates that are not today or yesterday.

```
Option Explicit

Sub notTodayOrYesterday()
    With Worksheets("Sheet5")
        If .AutoFilterMode Then .AutoFilterMode = False
        With .Cells(1, 1).CurrentRegion
            .AutoFilter Field:=12, Criteria1:=Format(Date, "\<\>mm/dd/yyyy"), _
                        Operator:=xlAnd, Criteria2:=Format(Date - 1, "\<\>mm/dd/yyyy")
        End With
        If .AutoFilterMode Then .AutoFilterMode = False
    End With
End Sub
```

Note that this was tested on a computer system with MDY regional settings. If it does not work for you and your system is DMY, change the date formats.

[image: not_today_yesterday]
            <sup>Before Autofilter applied</sup>

[image: not_today_yesterday]
            <sup>After Autofilter applied (before End Sub)</sup>